# Read tooltip of checkbox of using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have table with check boxes in it.and the CSS for the check box is GridCheckBox, I want to read the check boxes tool tip into an array with , separated. How can I.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
var tooltipTexts = $("#tableid input:checkbox.GridCheckBox").map(function(){
    return $(this).attr("title");
}).get().join(',');
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RAUe2/)

Comment: Hw to get only the checked list ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your tooltip text is in the `title` attribute of the checkbox, then you do the following:

```
var tooltips = [];

$(function(){
    $(".GridCheckBox").each(function(){
        tooltips.push($(this).attr("title"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Hw to get only the checked list ?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over it using `.each` and then use Array.join() to make it a string.

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dHCZt/

```
var titles = [];
$('.GridCheckBox').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('title')) {
        titles.push($(this).attr('title'));
    }
});

console.log(titles);
console.log(titles.join(','));
```

Comment: Hw to get only the checked list

Comment: @techonthenet just add `:checked` at the end of the selector `.gridCheckBox:checked`

Comment: @JhonP I tried this one and not working    var titles = [];
                $('#ListGrid .GridCheckBox:checked').each(function() {
                    if ($(this).attr('title')) {
                        titles.push($(this).attr('title'));
                    }
                });